# Even after Port forwarding in Docker cant run app with Local host

Tags: reactjs, docker, localhost

I am new to docker I want to build a image for my simple react app and want to run and view in local host.
At first container was exiting immediately after running , I solved it by searching many articles but now my problem is , even after successful running , port forwarding I can't view my app and page displays  local host didn't send any data.

This is my Docker file

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /movies
ADD package*.json ./
RUN  npm i
ADD . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

```
docker build -t movies:1.0 .   -> command  I used to build image
```

```
 docker run --interactive -d -p 3010:3000  --tty --entrypoint /bin/sh movies:1.0 
     -> command I used to run image
```

I have searched many articles but none helped , please help me.

Comment: The `--entrypoint` option is unnecessary, and tells Docker to run that interactive shell _instead of_ the `npm start` command the container would normally run.  Does deleting this option help ap all?

Comment: Hello If I remove --entry point container was exiting immediately after I run

Comment: That implies to me that `npm start` isn't working.  You might remove the `-d` option to let it start up in the foreground and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Man it is working fine when I removed -d it suddenly started working can you please explain why?

Comment: Also If  don't use -d while using github actions the job  was never ending it is  of course expected then how to make job done .